# connect.utils.parseSignedCookies deprecated, cookie storage with Express and Redis

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, redis

I'm reading *Building Scalable Apps with Redis and Node.js* and throughout there is code that doesn't work or is deprecated. I'm trying to use cookie storage with the code supplied to me:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
  connect = require('connect'),
  cookie = require('cookie'),
  expressSession = require('express-session'),
  ConnectRedis = require('connect-redis')(expressSession),
  redis = require('redis'),
  config = require('../config'),
  redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis'),
  redisSession = new ConnectRedis({host: config.redisHost, port: config.redisPort});

var socketAuth = function socketAuth(socket, next){
  var handshakeData = socket.request;
  var parsedCookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
  console.log(parsedCookie);



  var sid = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(parsedCookie['connect.sid'], config.secret);

  if (parsedCookie['connect.sid'] === sid)
    return next(new Error('Not Authenticated'));

  redisSession.get(sid, function(err, session){
    if (session.isAuthenticated)
    {
      socket.user = session.user;
      socket.sid = sid;
      return next();
    }
    else
      return next(new Error('Not Authenticated'));
  });
};
```

When I run the app, I get an error that says:

```
Cannot call method 'parseSignedCookies' of undefined
```

I'm 95% sure the problem begins here:

```
  var sid = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(parsedCookie['connect.sid'], config.secret);
```

I'm sure the problem lies with the fact that Connect is no longer used by Express, but what alternatives do I have to parse cookies? I may have to just completely rewrite the code and figure things out, but if anyone has any clever ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the module cookie-parser did the trick. Here is the code I added:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(parsedCookie['connect.sid'], config.secret);
```